# como guardar un rango de excel a acces con este codigo

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access-2007

Tengo este codigo vba de excel

```
Dim cs As String
Dim sPath As String
Dim sql As String
Dim sql2 As String
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection

sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\datos.accdb"
cs = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & sPath & ";Persist Security Info=False;"

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.Open cs

sql = "insert into tabla1 (nombre, apellido) values('" & Cells(1, 1).Value & "', '" & Cells(1, 2).Value & "')"


cn.Execute sql

cn.Close

Set cn = Nothing
```

este código solo me permite copiar una celda especifica, que debo modificar para que me seleccione un rango

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No se puede hacer un insert en una tabla de rangos, salvo que los mismos vengan de otro select.

En este caso, deberias hacer un loop por todas las celdas que queres ingresar, y ejecutar el insert para cada nueva posicion del cursor.

algo asi como  (no testeado):

```
for i = 1 to NN
    sql = "insert into tabla1 (nombre, apellido) values('" & Cells(i, 1).Value & "', '" & Cells(i, 2).Value & "')"
    cn.Execute sql
next i
```

Comment: hola amigo gracias por tu respuesta, me sale este error, te dejo imagen  https://image.prntscr.com/image/6b7f9c4a42964249b308081ea035c408.png

Comment: te avise que el codigo no estaba testeado.. es solo la demostracion de que se puede.. tenes que arreglar que es NN (no esta definido) y el execute solo tiene que estar una vez (adentro) @MarlonCamachoPolo

Comment: le puse un valor a nn priemro le puse 5 y luego 05 y me salio el mismo error, disculpa las molestias no soy programador, https://image.prntscr.com/image/dbfbbffd4aed412d8786dcd5bba84966.png

Comment: Y cual es el error que tira?

Comment: en la imagem que puse lo que sale en color amarillo, al ejecutarlo https://image.prntscr.com/image/b5088f8c0ebe4170bb74cde30890d602.png

Comment: ya lo solucione, borre "  cn.Execute sql " y listo, muchas gracias amigo, me sirvió mucho tu ayuda

Comment: Pero si borras el execute no hace nada ...

Comment: tienes razón, cuando salia el error copiaba la información y despues salia el error, ahora que quite eso, no funciona

Comment: tu codigo original funcionaba???

Comment: hola si, volvi a colocar lo que quite y ahora si funciona bien, que rraro dejo el codigo funcionado https://image.prntscr.com/image/a6bd54fb74244cbfa0ee83b1db2d712a.png   ,muchas gracias